# ReferenceError: Cannot access 'obj' before initialization

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, this

I have this object:

```js
const obj = {
  thing: 5,
  layer: {
    otherThing: obj.thing - 2
  }
}
```

error:

```
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'obj' before initialization
```

I tried to use `this` but it didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not something you can do in JavaScript. But you have two possible alternatives here:

1)

```js
    const obj = {thing: 5, layer: {}};
    obj.layer.otherThing = obj.thing - 2;
```

2) getters

```js
    const obj = {
       thing: 5,
       layer: {
          get otherThing(){obj.thing - 2}
       }
    }
```

Comment: didn't knew about getters, I will use that, thank you.